# Header missing error while decoding .mp3 file using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, decoding

[mp2 @ 0x555556aea340] Header missing
Error submitting the packet to the decoder
This above error is getting and i am unable to find out the reason.
I am decoding mp3 audio file using FFMPEG decode_audio.cpp pgm for which link is:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/decode_audio_8c-example.html
I want to decode file into .wav file.
if anyone can answer this it would be helpful for everyone whoever in future doing audio decoding part.

Comment: Hey. i am running the same example and getting the same error. Did you manage to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP2);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

This is for the MP2 audio codec to decode the audio. You need to customize the code for mp3.